# How do I combine rows with empty cells into one full row in python?

Tags: python

I have student test data for three types of tests that I would like to condense into one row per subject. Here is my current table:

```
StudentTestID   TestDate    SubjectName 1Label      1Value  2Label 2Value   
1000077         1-May       Math        Perf Level  3-NI                        
1000077         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  2-W                     
1000077         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level                              
1000077         1-May       Math                            Scaled 232          
1000077         1-Apr       ELA                             Scaled 214          
1000077         1-Jun       Science                         Scaled              
1000078         1-May       Math        Perf Level  2-W                     
1000078         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  4-P+                        
1000078         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level                              
1000078         1-May       Math                            Scaled 221          
1000078         1-Apr       ELA                             Scaled 215          
1000078         1-Jun       Science                         Scaled
```

And this is the desired output:

```
StudentTestID   TestDate    SubjectName 1Label      1Value  2Label 2Value   
1000077         1-May       Math        Perf Level  3-NI    Scaled 232                  
1000077         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  2-W     Scaled 214              
1000077         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level          Scaled                  
1000078         1-May       Math        Perf Level  2-W     Scaled 221                  
1000078         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  4-P+    Scaled 215              
1000078         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level          Scaled
```

I have tried various joins and groupby but I'm not getting the desired output. Examples of what I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['SubjectName'])
df.groupby(['StudentTestID'])
edf.join(edf.set_index('SubjectName'), on='SubjectName')
```

I am still relatively new to python so these were attempts after some googling but they did not achieve the desired output.

Comment: please post the query you've tried

Comment: Just to clarify you want the output to be 'One row per `SubjectName`  per `TestDate`', right?

Comment: @Eagnir correct

Answer (score 1):

Hope you enjoy it, Hope you are using pandas to work, I use simple and direct approach to solve this.

```py
#df = df.fillna('', inplace=True)  #uncomment it, if you are getting empty space

# create a new dataframe from old dataframe 
new_df = df[['StudentTestID','2Label','2Value']]
#  delete unwanted row 
new_df = new_df[new_df['2Label'].notna()]
#create another df to store 1label and 1 value 
new_df2 = df[['1Label','1Value']]
new_df2 = new_df2[new_df2['1Label'].notna()]
# use inner merge to dataframe
df = pd.merge(df, new_df, on= ['StudentTestID','2Label','2Value'], how= 'inner')
df['1Label'] = new_df2['1Label'].values
df['1Value'] = new_df2['1Value'].values
print(df)
```

here is the output,

```
    StudentTestID TestDate SubjectName    1Label   1Value 2Label  2Value
0        1000077    1-May        Math  Perf-Level   3-NI  Scaled   232.0
1        1000077    1-Apr         ELA  Perf-Level    2-W  Scaled   214.0
2        1000077    1-Jun     Science  Perf-Level    NaN  Scaled     NaN
3        1000078    1-May        Math  Perf-Level    2-W  Scaled   221.0
4        1000078    1-Apr         ELA  Perf-Level   4-P+  Scaled   215.0
5        1000078    1-Jun     Science  Perf-Level    NaN  Scaled     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are using pandas to do above things here is a solution.

*While typing the sol got a little lengthy but it's simply because I printed the output for each step, the answer itself is hardly five lines of code. So don't get overwhelmed by seeing the length. Happy coding!*

You can split the dataframe into different frames for different labels and use `merge` command (more on it later). First reproducing the given example

```py
# Recreating the given example
df = pd.DataFrame({'StudentTestID' : ['1000077','1000077','1000077','1000077','1000077','1000077','1000078','1000078','1000078','1000078','1000078','1000078'],
                   'TestDate' : ['1-May','1-Apr','1-Jun','1-May','1-Apr','1-Jun','1-May','1-Apr','1-Jun','1-May','1-Apr','1-Jun'],
                   'SubjectName' : ['Math', 'ELA', 'Science', 'Math', 'ELA', 'Science', 'Math', 'ELA', 'Science', 'Math', 'ELA', 'Science'],
                   '1Label' : ['Perf Level', 'Perf Level', 'Perf Level', '', '', '', 'Perf Level', 'Perf Level', 'Perf Level', '', '', ''],
                   '1Value' : ['3-NI', '2-W', '', '', '', '', '2-W', '4-P+', '', '', '', ''],
                   '2Label' : ['', '', '', 'Scaled', 'Scaled', 'Scaled', '', '', '', 'Scaled', 'Scaled', 'Scaled'],
                   '2Value' : ['', '', '', '232', '214', '', '', '', '', '221', '215', '']})

df

StudentTestID   TestDate    SubjectName 1Label       1Value   2Label    2Value
1000077            1-May    Math        Perf Level   3-NI       
1000077            1-Apr    ELA         Perf Level   2-W        
1000077            1-Jun    Science     Perf Level          
1000077            1-May    Math                               Scaled   232
1000077            1-Apr    ELA                                Scaled   214
1000077            1-Jun    Science                            Scaled   
1000078            1-May    Math        Perf Level    2-W       
1000078            1-Apr    ELA         Perf Level    4-P+      
1000078            1-Jun    Science     Perf Level          
1000078            1-May    Math                               Scaled   221
1000078            1-Apr    ELA                                Scaled   215
1000078            1-Jun    Science                            Scaled
```

We could split the dataframe based on labels

```py
# Getting only 1Label, 1Value and not 2Label, 2Value
df1 = df[['StudentTestID', 'TestDate', 'SubjectName', '1Label', '1Value']]

df1

StudentTestID   TestDate    SubjectName 1Label      1Value
1000077         1-May       Math        Perf Level  3-NI
1000077         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  2-W
1000077         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level  
1000077         1-May       Math        
1000077         1-Apr       ELA     
1000077         1-Jun       Science     
1000078         1-May       Math        Perf Level  2-W
1000078         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  4-P+
1000078         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level  
1000078         1-May       Math        
1000078         1-Apr       ELA     
1000078         1-Jun       Science
```

Now dropping the empty values based on `1Label` column

```py
df1 = df1[df1['1Label'] != '']    #Getting non-empty values
df1

StudentTestID   TestDate    SubjectName 1Label      1Value
1000077         1-May       Math        Perf Level  3-NI
1000077         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  2-W
1000077         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level  
1000078         1-May       Math        Perf Level  2-W
1000078         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  4-P+
1000078         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level
```

Similarly going for 2label, 2value

```py
df2 = df[['StudentTestID', 'TestDate', 'SubjectName', '2Label', '2Value']]
df2 = df2[df2['2Label'] != '']

df2

StudentTestID   TestDate    SubjectName 2Label  2Value
1000077         1-May       Math        Scaled  232
1000077         1-Apr       ELA         Scaled  214
1000077         1-Jun       Science     Scaled  
1000078         1-May       Math        Scaled  221
1000078         1-Apr       ELA         Scaled  215
1000078         1-Jun       Science     Scaled
```

Now we can merge them using `merge` command like below, oversimplifying it will put all the columns from both the dataframes into a single frame and return it (the common columns are not repeated)

```py
final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['StudentTestID', 'TestDate', 'SubjectName'])

final_df

StudentTestID   TestDate    SubjectName 1Label      1Value  2Label  2Value
1000077         1-May       Math        Perf Level  3-NI    Scaled  232
1000077         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  2-W     Scaled  214
1000077         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level          Scaled  
1000078         1-May       Math        Perf Level  2-W     Scaled  221
1000078         1-Apr       ELA         Perf Level  4-P+    Scaled  215
1000078         1-Jun       Science     Perf Level          Scaled
```

So the final good-to-go code is

```py
df1 = df[['StudentTestID', 'TestDate', 'SubjectName', '1Label', '1Value']]
df1 = df1[df1['1Label'] != '']
df2 = df[['StudentTestID', 'TestDate', 'SubjectName', '2Label', '2Value']]
df2 = df2[df2['2Label'] != '']
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['StudentTestID', 'TestDate', 'SubjectName'])
```